# QGIS -Tool for splitting a big dataset into smaller data sets and store them?

Tags: geopandas

I would like to split a bigger dataset into multiple smaller ones and store the smaller data sets. For example, I have a big point feature data set and would like to split it into, let's say, 4 parts, and then store the 4 smaller datasets. Is there some tool in QGIS (or geopandas) to do this?

I know that you can create a grid and then join to the ids of the grids, then select and export as  ect, but if there is a tool which makes it easier to split the dataset by just defining the amount of pieces the data should be splitted in, this would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also split based on the id of the features:

1. Use [`Field Calculator`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) to create a new field `quartils` with this expression using [`quartils` (`q1` and `q3`)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#q1) and [`median`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_nearest#median) functions:

   ```
   case 
    when $id >= q3 ($id) then 1
    when $id >= median ($id) then 2
    when $id >= q1 ($id) then 3
    else 4
   end
   ```
2. Run [`Split vector layer`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer) with the field quartils from step 1 as `Unique ID field`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there ist: the SAGA-Tool 'Split features layer', which does exaxtly what I described above: You can specify the amount of pieces by defining a relevant grid (if you want 4 pieces, you create a grid with 4 cells etc). As output it creates 4 parts (as shapefile).

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the end, I must say, even though this tool is okay for middlesized data, but for a file about 1GB it already takes quite a while, and you can not define the name of the outputfiles. If you have a single file which needs to be splitted, then this is okay, but it is not very useful in automation task (so when you want to split multiple files).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a column of repeated numbers and groupby this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import os
df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\1000points.geojson")
n_subsets = 6 #Number of subsets to create

#Create a column of repeated numbers: 0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5, ...
df["subset_group"] = np.tile(range(n_subsets), df.shape[0])[:df.shape[0]]

out_folder = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\outoutout"
for subsetnum, subsetframe in df.groupby("subset_group"):
    out_file = os.path.join(out_folder, f"output_{subsetnum}.geojson")
    print(subsetframe.shape[0])
    subsetframe.to_file(out_file)
    # 167
    # 167
    # 167
    # 167
    # 166
    # 166
```

[image]